# Qual a diferença de "Future.whenComplete" e "Future.then"?

Tags: async, dart

A linguagem Dart fornece diversos mecanismos para lidar com chamdas assíncronas. Um que estou muito habituado é o modificar `await`, que pode ser usado em funções marcadas como `async`.

Porém, de toda sorte, as vezes estamos em uma função que não está marcada como assíncrona, e nesses casos somos apresentados a objetos da classe `Future`. Essa classe possui alguns métodos que eu posso assinalar como `callbacks`:

- `then()`
- `whenComplete()`
- `catchError()`

A documentação de contexto que o VS Code fornece sobre o `catchErro()` me é bem clara (tradução livre):

> Manipula erros emitidos por este `Future`

Mas fiquei confuso quanto ao uso de `then()` e o de `whenComplete()`. Sobre `then()`:

> Registra *callbacks* a serem chamados quando este `Future` completar

E o `whenComplete()`:

> Registra uma função a ser chamada quando este `Future` completar

Então, fica a minha dúvida:

- qual a diferença entre ambos os métodos?
- qual o caso clássico de chamada de `then()`? qual o caso clássico de chamada de `whenComplete()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `whenComplete` simplesmente é chamado quando o `Future` se completa: quando o valor que o `Future` resgata finalmente é obtido. Note que a função passada *não tem argumentos*, é um simples saber que o `Future` se completou.

Por exemplo, usando o [`sqflite`](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite), temos a opção de chamar o método `Database.rawInsert`, que retorna um `id` relativo à alteração.

Se, por acaso, me interessa apenas *saber* que a consulta foi concluída (para o bem ou para o mal), posso fazer o seguinte:

```dart
Database db = ...;

Future<dynamic> insercao = db.rawInsert("INSERT (a, b) INTO TABLE values ('valor', 'outro valor')");

insercao.whenComplete(() => print('o futuro chegou!'));
```

Já o `then` permite que você **intereja com o futuro** ou, ainda mais, **altere o futuro** retornado.

[image: De volta para o futuro]

Por exemplo, posso ter uma consulta que me retorne múltiplos elementos, mas me interessa apenas o primeiro:

```dart
Database db = ...;

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> primeiroDado = db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM TABLE).then((l) => l.first);
```

Note que o futuro retornado não é mais uma lista de mapas, mas simplesmente um único mapa. Essa transformação foi feita usando o `then()` e pode ser feita em partes síncronas do código.

Se estiver trabalhando em funções assíncronas, é mais natural usar um `T myValue = await myFuture` e trabalhar em cima de `myValue`. Nos exemplos acima:

```dart
// no lugar do whenComplete()
Database db = ...;

await db.rawInsert("INSERT (a, b) INTO TABLE values ('valor', 'outro valor')");

print('o futuro chegou!');

// no lugar do then()

Database db = ...;

Map<String, dynamic> primeiroDado = (await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM TABLE)).first;
```

> Em breve devo subir um uso mais natural dessas funções.